# Having trouble using bytea field in postres when using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

Anyone using bytea field type in postgres and gorm?
I'm having trouble if anyone could help me or give me a clue
I'm storing bytes of slice of string and when fetching the records, all fields are fetched except the bytea field. It just show empty
Struct

```golang
type Service struct {
    Name          string           `gorm:"name" json:"name" form:"name" query:"name"`
    Slug          string           `gorm:"slug" json:"slug" form:"slug" query:"slug"`
    ProtocolsByte []byte           `gorm:"protocols" json:"-"`
    Protocols     []string         `json:"protocols" gorm:"-"`
    Features      []ServiceFeature `json:"features"`
    db.BaseModel
}

func (p *Service) AfterFind(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    fmt.Println(p.ProtocolsByte) // Empty
    return
}
```

And DB has data like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6zUq.png
Any help is appreciated